# Is there a free photo competition hosting software?

Tags: webapp-rec

I'd like to host a photo competition with some of my coworkers, but we have no internal site that would allow voting on photos. Does anyone know of a site that would allow uploading and voting on photos for free?

Researching the web, I've found numerous image viewing sites, but non with voting options.

Comment: I've found http://www.simpleviewer.net/simpleviewer/ - if I could find something like this that is opensource so I can add an 'up/down' feature that'd be great!

Comment: This sounds similar to the website [crowdspring.com](http://www.crowdspring.com/), however, it's not a free service. It was [used to find a logo for SuperUser](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/superuser-com-logo-vote/).

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Facebook. Create a Facebook Page or Group and allow the fans/users to add photos to the page. Then, you guys can vote on photos by Liking them. So then, just see which photos have the most Likes.

That'd be a simple solution, but trying to track the most Likes would be a manual process.

Comment: You cant hold competition on facebook.

Comment: Its against the promotional rules... You will not offer any contest, giveaway, or sweepstakes ("promotion") on Facebook without our prior written consent. If we consent, you take full responsibility for the promotion, and will follow our Promotions Guidelines and all applicable laws.  http://www.facebook.com/promotions_guidelines.php

Answer (score 0):

you can try http://www.mediaecho.com.sg/. However, like crowdspring (as suggested by Senseful), MediaEcho also not a free service.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about exactly free picture-competition software, but placing the photos on ordinary free gallery and then creating a topic with voting on any forum might be the workaround.